# Connect TFS Team Projects to Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, tfs

For my TFS, i have two projects inside my project collection. I have connected one of them to my site collection in SharePoint 2007. But I need to connect the both of them to the same site collection, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this is possible. if you see when you configure the URL for SharePoint sites, TFS only allow you add single url.

I think it is not a good idea to have multiple site collection for single team project, it will complex the situation. You may think about team project collection

Comment: I meant, i need to connect two team projects to one site collection, is that possible?